# How to check if managed_file has uploaded a video and use it in states

Tags: 8, forms, files

I want to disable the submit button in a form for as long as there are no value/uploaded video in a managed_file but I can't seem to find what form name or element property I have to check for in `#states`.

I have the following:

```
$form['file'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('File'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Choose video to upload.'),
  '#upload_validators' => $validators,
];
$form["submit"] = [
  "#type" => "submit",
  "#value" => t('Submit'),
  '#states' => [
    'enabled' => [
      ':input[name="file"]' => ['empty' => FALSE],
    ],
  ],
];
```

I've also tried using `value => true`, `:input[name="files[0]` and `:input[name="files[file]` without luck. How can I enable the submit button when file has been processed?

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the comments in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x), there are several things to look out for:

1. You may need to target the element's widget, as mentioned in this [comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/62873#comment-62873). Most likely you would do this in a `#process` callback or in a form alter hook.

> This is a good nuance to understand - thanks! Targeting the widget
> worked for me on a number field. It gets ignored otherwise.

```
// My number field is hidden unless repeat is selected
$form['field_myfield_num']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="field_myfield_select"]' => ['value' => (string) 'repeat'],
    ],
];

// My number field is set as required when repeat is selected.
$form['field_myfield_num']['widget']['0']['value']['#states'] = [
  'required' => [
    ':input[name="field_myfield_select"]' => ['value' =>  (string) 'repeat'],
  ],
];
```

2. In the same comment above, we also see that sometimes it helps to cast your candidate value to a string: `['value' =>  (string) 'repeat']`. I've also seen this explicitly mentioned elsewhere, but can't find the reference.
3. It is possible to test for a negation using `'!value'`, as seen in this [comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/63092#comment-63092):

> I had a form with a field of #type select_or_other, which renders like
> radios. I wanted to enable the submit button when the form element was
> not "none". The following worked for me:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Donate'),
  '#button_type' => 'primary',
  '#states' => [
    'enabled' => [
      ':input[name="amount[select]"]' => ['!value' => 'none'],
    ],
  ],
```